# How to run cmd command with exec command in ImageJ and show printout/progress in external cmd window (not headless)

Tags: windows, cmd, imagej

I want to start an R sript from imageJ macro (IJM language) and do this using the exec command. `exec(path_to_R path_to_script);` this script takes a long time to run, and I would like to monitor the progress of it at runtime. However the cmd window is not open, and I only get the print statements in the imageJ log when the script is compleated. Is there a way to show the cmd window while the scrip is running?

I am running this script on both Windows 7 and Windows 10

Two simple test examples are:

`exec('cmd /c "help"');` # That I want to very quickly show the help output, but now it is returned to imageJ log after compleation

and `exec('cmd /c "Timeout 5"');` # That I want to have as a separate cmd window that is open for 5 seconds.

I have attempted to open a second cmd from the one that is started from ImageJ, but could not find the correct syntax. 
I tried e.g. `exec('cmd start cmd /c Timeout 5');` but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote this question I figured it out. I was missing an /c in the first cmd call.

The function `exec('cmd /c start cmd /c Timeout 5');` will call cmd open a new cmd that is being shown and show this window for 5 seconds.

I hope this can help someone else